# set interval line not working in react js

Tags: reactjs

https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-wind-u0c9k?file=/src/App.js - full code link

```
  useEffect(() => {
    Object.values(setdata).map((val) => {
      getPostData(val.Player, val.IP, val.Port, val.ChannelName);       
      //return fetchdata;
      setInterval(() => {
        getPostData(val.Player, val.IP, val.Port, val.ChannelName);       
      }, 500);
    });
   }, [setdata])
```

I want to set up the set interval in code but not able to do that when I use set Interval I got (Image). I fetch the time code from localhost and want that when time code run from back end the time  also run in front end but when I use set interval in GUI array type list goes.

[image: GUI Image]

want this type UI to show running time
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNwdt.png)

Answer (score 0):

setData is not an object it's an array.

**NOTE: Make sure you clear the interval on every rerender.**

```
useEffect(() => {
  const intervals = setdata.map((val) => {
    getPostData(val.Player, val.IP, val.Port, val.ChannelName);
    const interval = setInterval(() => getPostData(val.Player, val.IP, val.Port, val.ChannelName), 500);
    return interval
  });
  return () => intervals.forEach(clearInterval);
}, [setdata]);
```

Comment: thank you for reply, but its not working